# Insufficient power from pwr.p.test

Tags: binomial-distribution, experiment-design, simulation, statistical-power, proportion

Using the `pwr` package, I determined the optimal sample size of 38. However, when I ran simulations using this sample size, I only get a power of 70%. What's going on?

The null is `p = 15%`. The true data-generating process is `p = 5%`.

````r
library(dplyr)
library(pwr)

set.seed(123)

pwr_n <- pwr.p.test(h = ES.h(0.05, 0.15),  # Ho: p = 0.15
                    n = NULL,
                    sig.level = 0.10,
                    power = 0.80,
                    alternative = "less")

pwr_n$n
# [1] 38.0115

conf_90 <- function(i){
  set.seed(i)
  
  x <- rbinom(n=round(pwr_n$n), size=1, prob=0.05) # True p = 0.05
  
  out <- binom.test(sum(x), length(x), conf.level=0.90, alternative = "less")
  # out <- prop.test(sum(x), length(x), conf.level=0.90, alternative = "less")
  
  
  return(out$conf.int)
  
}

intervals <- lapply(1:10000, conf_90)

df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, intervals))

names(df) <- c("lower", "upper")

# Ho: p = 0.15

df$Type2Error <- df$upper >= 0.15

head(df)

# power

1 - sum(df$Type2Error) / nrow(df)

# [1] 0.6977

```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The major reason this is not giving you the expected power is because apparently, this `pwr.p.test` function [uses a normal approximation](https://github.com/cran/pwr/blob/master/R/pwr.p.test.R#L35).

A normal approximation to a binomial process works well if $p \approx \frac{1}{2}$ and $n$ is large. Neither is the case in your problem, since $p=0.05$, $n=1$.

The simulation is therefore much more indicative of the power you can expect.

Some tips for improving the simulation:

- You are estimating a *minimal* sample size to obtain sufficient power. Don't round it down, but use `ceiling` instead.
- You need only set a seed at the start of the simulation. Setting the seed to `i` guarantees that for all simulations, you are using the same order of the RNG, which surely is not what wanted to do.